# Поведение объекта, унаследовавшего нативный прототип

Tags: javascript, prototype

Мне нужно создать объект моего личного класса (допустим, MediaObject). Для этого я пишу функцию -

```
function MediaObject(){...}
```

После чего я могу прототипировать её:

```
MediaObject.prototype.func=function(){...};
```

Очевидно, при создании инстанса этого класса я смогу пользоваться всем этим; но вопрос заключается в том, как мне заставить мой объект действовать, как один из нативных? Допустим, я хочу, чтобы он вёл себя, как нода, то есть я пишу

```
MediaObject.prototype=Object.create(Node.prototype);
```

И в итоге мой класс наследует класс `Node` и все его функции. Но если я захочу вызвать метод вроде `document.body.appendChild(new MediaObject())`, то это не сработает, потому что это объект класса MediaObject, а не Node. Как заставить объект вести себя точно так же, как и объекты наследуемого класса, чтобы можно было совершать с ними те же действия, но при этом это оставалось моим объектом, не замусоривающим глобальные прототипы?

Answer (score 1):

Во-1ых, у вас путаница с терминами. То, что вы называете *нативными объектами*, на самом деле *объекты среды*. О том, какая разница между ними, можно почитать например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614317/what-is-the-difference-between-native-objects-and-host-objects).

В-2ых, 
[Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) - это не класс, а **интерфейс** объекта среды. Вообще говоря, классов как таковых в JavaScript нет (вернее не было до ES6), есть только [прототипы объектов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). Прототип нативного объекта может наследовать только от прототипа нативного же объекта (определенного средствами JavaScript, т.е. вами же либо другим программистом). А интерфейсы DOM вообще не предназначены для наследования, у них и прототипов то нет. Для примера, посмотрите на тот же [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

Comment: Спасибо. То есть иначе как путём добавления в прототип интерфейса DOM методы не добавить? Получается, можно только создать объект DOM внутри моего класса и оперировать с ним?

Comment: Похоже вы все еще не понимаете принципы работы с DOM. Вы **не можете создать** (в буквальном смысле) объект DOM. Все что вы можете - создать элемент на странице (методами DOM), а соответствующий объект создается средой исполнения (браузером) _без вашего участия_. Но вы можете получить доступ к такому объекту для последующих манипуляций с DOM-элементом (но не объектом напрямую). Это и называется **интерфейс**.